# Position h1 with border in center of picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a banner with Bootstrap 3, and the end result should look like this, and have a height off `350px;`

[image]

A demoversion off the code I have until now can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/banner-template.html).

I am not sure how I can make the `h1` and `p` tag align in the middle? At the moment they are at the top, and I cannot figure out how to position them.

When I look on `< 768px` the picture is way to big. Is that because of the `cover` in the `header` tag? How can I make that picture get smaller on `< 768px`?

```css
header {
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url('https://img2.picload.org/image/daapipii/header-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  header {
    /*height:100%;*/
    background-attachment:inherit;
    height:100vh;
  }
}

header h1 {
  /*background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.36);*/
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border:5px solid rgba(108,111,119,0.19);
  /*box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #333;*/
}

header h1 {
  font-family:'Aladin';
  font-size:71px;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size:41px;
  }
}

header p {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
  font-size:26px;
  font-weight:600;
  font-family:'Source Sans Pro';
  /*letter-spacing:2px;*/
  color:#f5f5f5;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #111;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  header p {
    font-size:17px;
  }
}

header .row.no-space p {
  text-align:right;
}
/* Social Media Position */
header .row.no-space {
  margin-top:initial;
  bottom:0px;
  position:fixed;
  right:20px;
}

header .fa {
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333;
  padding:7px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-bg">
                    <h1>Welcome on free feelings</h1></div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Animated header with scroll engine </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hidden-xs no-space">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vertically center the content on the page, I would use CSS flexbox on your `<header>` element like this:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Regarding the size of the image, would it be acceptable to align the text to the top of the page on mobile?

If so, then I would suggest removing the `height: 100vh` and flexbox from the header on mobile. Instead you need a responsive image in relation to the screen width but since you are using a background image you can do this:

```
header {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 0; /* Use padding-bottom to define height */
  padding-bottom: 62%; /*Aspect ratio of image (h/w*100)*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. I can see that I actually do not need the cover. Is it correct to set the `width:100%` then? The banner should fill out 1200px.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The header is already full width - you do not need to specify `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the bottom of your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
}

.text-bg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I cannot see that this one is solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this old school you can use the `display: table` approach (which is not what is recomended these days):

```css
header {
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url('https://img2.picload.org/image/daapipii/header-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The current recommended way usually is with `Flex` which is cleaner and nicer. If you want to keep all as is then you just change your header CSS to:

```css
header {
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url('https://img2.picload.org/image/daapipii/header-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. I can see that I actually do not need the cover. Is it correct to set the `width:100%` then? The banner should fill out 1200px.